# standard c output won't print to console

Tags: c++11, console, centos7, cout

I have encountered a very strange issue with printing to console using `std::cout` in a c++11 application under `CentOS`.

```
printf("Before...\n");  // This gets printed with no issue
std::cout << "This won't be printed to console\n" << std::flush; // This won't get printed
std::cout.flush();
printf("After...\n");  // This gets printed with no issue
```

The output in the console is:

```
Before...
After...
```

The `cout` message for some reason is not printed. There is no `stdout` redirection in my code. I purposely redirected `cout` to a file but the issue was not solved. I am confused as to where to track down the issue.

What would prevent `cout` from printing? In what potential scenarios, `cout` stops functioning? What could be the issue?

Comment: This snippet of course works if I try it in a `main`. You will need to cut down your code until you find the offending statement - it's not one of the 4 you show here. So we cannot help you.

Comment: In your opinion, what would prevent `cout` from printing? In what potential scenarios `cout` stops functioning properly?

Comment: I am dealing with a large code. I am gonna try to cut down to hopefully find the issue which could take me a couple of days.

Comment: The trick is to repeatedly cut 50% of your code. If the problem remains, it's in the remaining 50% of the code. If it disappears, the problem was caused by something in the 50% you removed. This is essentially a fast binary search.